# My media queries are not working

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I know that there are lots of questions that look like this one, but nothing has worked for me so far. I have an unique CSS document for a whole website and, at the bottom of this document, I have this:

```
@media (max-width: 1250){

    #opcoes{
        display: none;
    }

    #expresso{
        display: none;
    }

}
```

Basically, my site template is designed like this:

```
<body>

<div id = "menu">
</div>

<div id = "principal>
</div>

<div id = "opcoes">
   <div id = "expresso">
   </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Apparently, my "opcoes" and "expresso" div are not disappearing when I reduce the browser width to less than 1250. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `length-unit` in your `@media` condition. Use:

```
@media (max-width: 1250px){...}
```

Comment: oh god hahaha thanks a lot man, accepting your answer as soon as possible